# MySQL select subqueries

Tags: mysql, joomla1.7

This is what I have at the moment.

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('`#__catalog_commit`.`id` as id, `#__catalog_commit`.`date` as date, COUNT(`#__catalog_commit_message`.`commit_id`) as count,
    (SELECT COUNT(`#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_notice FROM `#__catalog_commit_message` WHERE `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type` = 1 GROUP BY `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_notice,
    (SELECT COUNT(`#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_warning FROM `#__catalog_commit_message` WHERE `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type` = 2 GROUP BY `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_warning,
    (SELECT COUNT(`#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_error FROM `#__catalog_commit_message` WHERE `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type` = 3 GROUP BY `#__catalog_commit_message`.`type`) as count_error');
    $query->from('#__catalog_commit_message');
    $query->leftjoin('`#__catalog_commit` ON `#__catalog_commit`.`id` = `#__catalog_commit_message`.`commit_id`');
    $query->group('`#__catalog_commit_message`.`commit_id`');
    $query->order('`#__catalog_commit`.`id` DESC');
```

What I have is 2 tables with the following structures:

```
catalog_commit
==============
id
date

catalog_commit_message
======================
id
commit_id
type
message
```

Basically I want to have the count of each different types of messages per group items. In what I have it actually select every rows (Which is normal) but I'm looking for a way (nicier if possible) to have the count per messages type within the query.

EDIT: Just wanted to add that it's a JModelList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, this should be your query:

```
SELECT c.id
      ,c.date
      ,count(cm.commit_id) as ct_total
      ,sum(CASE WHEN cm.type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_notice
      ,sum(CASE WHEN cm.type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_warning
      ,sum(CASE WHEN cm.type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_error
FROM   catalog_commit c 
LEFT   JOIN catalog_commit_message cm ON cm.commit_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.id, c.date
ORDER  BY c.id DESC
```

You had the order of your tables reversed in the `LEFT JOIN`. Also, you had weird subqueries in the SELECT list.